# How to read an array of long values inside a json object value in JSON.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, json, json.net

I have a json like following.

```
"bookshelf": {
               "shelfId": 5752814017970176,
               "shelfName": "Novels",
               "description": null,
               "bookOrder": "[5720369633689600, 5631072867975168, 5765651641663488, 5685154290860032, 4675571090980864, 4721509306204160]",
               "createrType": "TEACHER",
           }
```

I need to read the value **bookOrder** as an array of long values. How to do that using Json.net in c#?

Answer (score 0):

First, your book order list should be a proper array. There you have a string.

```
"bookshelf": {
    "shelfId": 5752814017970176,
    "shelfName": "Novels",
    "description": null,
    "bookOrder": [5720369633689600, 5631072867975168, 5765651641663488, 5685154290860032, 4675571090980864, 4721509306204160],
    "createrType": "TEACHER",
}
```

Once you fix that you can convert that prop into an array of longs.

```
var j = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(json);
Console.WriteLine(j["bookshelf"]["bookOrder"].ToObject<long[]>()[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Json string produces a class like this:

```
public class RootObject
    {
        public Bookshelf bookshelf { get; set; }
    }
public class Bookshelf
{
    public long shelfId { get; set; }
    public string shelfName { get; set; }
    public object description { get; set; }
    public long[] bookOrder { get; set; }
    public string createrType { get; set; }
}
```

You can then get `bookOrder` like this:

```
RootObject library=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
long[] bookOrders=library.bookshelf.bookOrder;
```

**Test:**

```
foreach(var num in bookOrders)
{
  Console.WriteLine(num);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [Querying Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJson.htm) to get array of long values by using indexer like

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(@"Path to your json file");

JToken jToken = JToken.Parse(json);

var longArray = jToken["bookshelf"]["bookOrder"].ToObject<long[]>();
```

Then you can print you long arrays like

```
foreach (long item in longArray)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

**Output:**

[image]